# How can I detect syntax errors due to invisible characters in Sublime Text?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext

The [1] is copy paste from the ruby file, and [2] is valid

```
[1] pry(main)> " do ".bytes
=> [32, 100, 111, 194, 160]
[2] pry(main)> " do ".bytes
=> [32, 100, 111, 32]
```

Ruby syntax validation only gives the last line of the file which makes it hard to find the problem

```
$ ruby -c class/test.rb
class/test.rb:123: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: is that the complete error you got?

Comment: I copied the line right from your question (both the rendered version and the one available by hitting the [edit] link) and get `[32, 100, 111, 32]`. Not sure where your invisible character is...

Comment: It was probably removed by stackoverflow since it's probably not a legal character in most encoding. And it's invisible in both sublime text and iTerm 2.

Comment: it's the complete error yes

Answer (score 1):

Use `SublimeLinter` package for sublime text to validate ruby syntax,

**SublimeLinter:**

This one is actually three separate packages: **SublimeLinter, SublimeLinter-Ruby, and SublimeLinter-rubocop.**

With these installed, Sublime lints my Ruby code as I type! If I’m not satisfied with the default rules, I can tweak style enforcement using ~.rubocop.yml. Check out the Rubocop documentation for details.

**[Here is the sublime package for ruby syntax](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-rubocop)**

**[A beautiful documentation for sublime3 packages](https://mattbrictson.com/sublime-text-3-recommendations)**

**Rubocop style violations in yellow. (If there were Ruby syntax errors, they would appear in red.)**

Comment: i'll try next time I have the problem but I don't think it will highlight the right line since ruby itself only warns about the last end in the file not being expected